# Visiual Studio - Trying to add variables taken from other forms into a table

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to add data to a table using variables taken from other forms. I'm using is :

```
 using (SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection())
        {
            test.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ASUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BookStoreBiggest;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Order(CustomerID, BookID) Values (@CustomerID, @BookID)", test);
            xp4.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ClientName.clientID;
            xp4.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ClientsMDI.IDB;
            test.Open();
            xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            test.Close();
        }
```

I can add data with values generated in the same form however when I try to use ClientName.clientID and ClientsMDI.IDB I get

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid object name 'Order'.
```

I've added the variable as:

```
public static int clientID;
```

Comment: Order is a keyword use [Order]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool.

So that you can mark an answer.

Order is a keyword use [Order] it will escape the keywork.

Try not to name tables or columns after keywords like order, group, by, select ... etc